# Open ball with a radius tending to $0$ and adherent point

Tags: general-topology

Hello !
First $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} x \in B(x_0, \varepsilon) \iff d(x_0, x) \le 0$ because the limit turns $\lt$ into $\le$ and then $x = x_0$. But with the definition of an adherent point of $A$ :
$$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, B(x_0, \varepsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$$
With the limit, we have : $\{x_0\} \cap A \neq \emptyset \iff x_0 \in A$ 

And this is false (in $\mathbb{R}$ $0$ is not in $(0, 1]$).

So where is the mistake ? Can we use the limits with the radius in this context ? (sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is : let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$, then $ \{x_{0}\} = \cap_{\epsilon > 0}B(x_{0},\epsilon)$ because for any $x_{1}\neq x_{0} $ there is an $\epsilon_{1}> 0$ such that $d(x_{0},x_{1})> \epsilon_{1}$.

The problem is for any $\epsilon>0$, $B(x_{0},\epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (for any **fixed** $\epsilon$ we can find at least one point in $A$, that is close to $x_{0}$) does not imply that $\cap_{\epsilon > 0}B(x_{0},\epsilon)\cap A \neq \emptyset$(there is a point in $A$, that can be **arbitrarily close** to $x_{0}$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even if $\varepsilon$ is fixed, we can chose it as close to $0$ as possible, no ? In fact I want to understand this because I want to prove that if we have $\forall x \in A ~ \forall y \in B, x \lt y$ and $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$, we have $\sup A = \inf B$ (without using series)

Comment: Once $\epsilon$ is chosen, it's fixed, so the order of 1) choosing $\epsilon$;  2) choosing a point $a$ in $A$ that has distance to $x_0$ smaller than $\epsilon$; matters a lot.

Comment: Let $A,B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying your conditions and both are non-empty, then because $A$ is bounded from above and $B$ is bounded from below, we know there is real number $a = \sup A$ and $b = \inf B$ by the least-upper-bounded property. To show that $a= b$, prove by contradiction, if $a > b$, then there is a $c$ such that $a > c > b$, and by definition of $a,b$, there is a point $x \in A, y \in B$ such that $a>x>c>y>b$, contradicting. Then if $a<b$, then there is $d$, such that $a<d<b$, which will contradict the conditon that the intersection of closures is nonempty.

Comment: Thanks but is it possible tu solve this thanks to a number in $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ ? I mean if we start with $\ell \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, if we express $\ell$ ?

Comment: First, you can show that $l$ is unique, then because it's in the closure of $B$, it must be greater or equal to any given point $x \in A$, otherwise $l<x$ for some $x$ would imply that there is an open set $(l-e,x)$, that is disjoint with $B$. Hence $l$ is an upper bound and it's in closure of $A$, so it must be the least upper bound.

Comment: Ok, I see. But I still don't understand why I can't take $\varepsilon$ small. We can set it because if we set $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 0 < \varepsilon_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \varepsilon_n = 0$, we can use $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_n$ for a certain $n$, then the radius tends to $0$ and the open ball is equal to $\{x_0\}$ (with $x_0$ the center). So why I can't take this series here ?

Comment: You will find out that taking limit is tricky, you need to be careful about what you mean. Take your question, consider $0$ and $(0,1]$. The followings hold: 1. for any $e>0$, there is a point $a_e$ in $(0,1]$ such that $|a_e| <e$; 2. for any point $a$ in $(0,1]$, there is a $e_a >0$ such that $a > e_a$. Notice the dependence.

Comment: If we rewrite the adherent point of A definition : $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 ~ \exists x \in A, d(x_0, x) \lt \varepsilon$ and with the limit, $x_0$ is not inevitably in $A$, I think the previous definition I had gave of an adherent point has disturbed me